# How do I access the 'hidden' index in my array? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

This is what my original dataframe looks like:
[image: Original dataframe]

Column 0 of the above dataframe corresponds to the `foracid` column

After subsetting this data and feeding it into a model, the output that I want to relate back to the original dataframe looks like this:

[image: Output]

The left column here relates to the `year_month` column of the orignal dataframe, but column 0 is the right column. The information is obviously there, I want to know how I can get these `year_month` values so I can relate it back to the original dataframe.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the value you are looking it work with in the `index` value for the dataframe, then you need:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

This will create a new index from 0 to n and a new column with the index.